# Apache Daemon JVM mode useless with only jre uninstalled

Tags: java, apache, service, daemon

I am trying to use Daemon to pack my exe to become a Windows service. And I found that if the StartMode/StopMode is JVM, the environment must have installed jdk. If not, the service can't work. Also I try to specify the full path of jvm.dll (I have an uninstalled jre folder), but not work too. **So, does jvm mode works with no installed jdk, just a jre folder?**

```
%APP_HOME%\prunsrv.exe //IS//MyService --DisplayName="My Service" --Description="My Service Description" ^
                --Install=%APP_HOME%\prunsrv.exe --Startup=auto ^
                --Jvm="E:\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll" ^
                --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=com.xx.temp.Main --StartMethod=start ^
                --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=com.xx.temp.Main --StopMethod=stop ^
                --Classpath=%APP_HOME%\stop.jar ^
                --StartParams=-service ^
                --StopTimeout=10 ^
                --StdOutput=%APP_HOME%\temp.txt --LogPath=./logs ^
                --StdError=%APP_HOME%\error.txt
```

By the way, I have thought **"--StopTimeout=10"** means if the stop program of service is not end after 10 seconds, then system will end the service by force. But it's not work too?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I didn't specify the **--JavaHome** parameter. So Daemon will use **JAVA_HOME** in the Environment if I have installed JDK. This is the real reason.